# EmberJS: Using helpers in component properties

Tags: ember.js, data-binding, view-helpers, computed-properties

I'm trying to sweeten this component template:

```
{{#link-to 'invoice' model.next.id }}
  {{format-number model.next.amount format="USD"}} due {{format-relative model.next.due units="day"}}
{{/link-to}}
```

As you can see, the verbosity makes it hard to see the final link text. The following is easier to parse:

```
{{#link-to 'invoice' model.next.id }}
  {{amount}} due {{date}}
{{/link-to}}
```

To enable this syntax I'm thinking computed properties will help, but I'm unsure how to leverage the `format-number` and `format-relative` helpers from within my component definition.

So, how do I add sugar to my component so this `{{format-number model.next.amount format="USD"}}` becomes this `{{amount}}`? Am I on the right track?

Comment: I would think your `format-number` helper should be a function that can be called from JavaScript (and the RegisterHelper call just refers to it.)

Comment: Yeah, just trying to figure out how to actually reference and used registered helpers outside of a template. It's imported from the `ember-intl` library.